# A question about some notation involving the exclamation mark

Tags: notation, regularization

What does the symbol ‘!’ signify? Is it $ \text{argmin} $? For example, $ \| A x - y \| = \min! $.

Comment: regarding tikhonov regularization: ||Ax-y||^2+h^2||x||^2=min!

Comment: This question would be more readable if there were a reference to a place where the notation is used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is an alternative notation for argmin. [Related discussion here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.research/3A3mHmCKbkc)

It seems similar to the notation $\exists ! X $ for *there is exactly one $ X $*, since both notations refer to a selection of an element of a set.

Comment: thank you!!  seems the notation has german roots? I had never seen it before